# alignment in assembly, how does each get its offset?

Tags: assembly, x86, alignment

This is a question I was working on, but I only want to know why the offsets are the way it is (the little red numbers)

[image: pic]

Can someone explain to me why in `struct s1`, the offset went from `0->4->8`? From what I understand, since `char` is 1 byte, there are 3 char's. so it's 3 bytes plus 1, to satisfy alignment. But why does it go from 4 to 8, at `union u1 b`?? Does `union` has 4 bytes? why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The union is 4 bytes because that is the size of the largest element it contains, namely a pointer (this must be a 32-bit platform)